# I'm looking for a "game girl"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning, adjectives

Let's say someone is going to introduce himself to a girl and talk about his tendencies, inclinations and interests. He tends to say:
I've always looked for for a girl who is OK with most of the suggestions I make or be pleased by any any types of music I like to listen, any genre of movies I'd like to watch or any place I propose to visit. Of course she has her own ideas and can express her feelings by facing anything she dislikes, just she is not a killjoy!

I know what adjective is used to describe such a person in casual English:

**Game:** (as an adjective means:)

> Willing to do things that are new, difficult, or that involve risks:

- It was a difficult challenge, but Roberta was game.
- She's game for anything. [[Source]](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/game)

Just as I mentioned, the person needs to say:

> - I'm looking for a game girl.

When I search this on the Internet, just a pornographic webpage appears.
I was wondering if this sentence has a specific application (sexual) or it is an idiomatic way of saying that (maybe the contents on these pages are not written by native speakers and this word is not useable in this case.)

Comment: You should definitely be ***very, very*** careful about using ***game*** in such contexts, given the possible allusion to girls who are ***on the game*** (they work as prostitutes). Besides which, even if you say *That girl's up for anything!*, half your audience (basically, the ***men*** :) might be inclined to understand that as primarily meaning the girl is willing to have sex with them.

Comment: I wouldn't spend too much time on figuring this out -- this guy is not actually looking for a human being, just a minion. There does not exist a person who likes whatever a guy likes and doesn't ever want it her own way.

Comment: But @FeliniusRex this is not a matter of logic behind a sentence which can be originated from another cultures most profound belief that can be not even imaginable for a member of another society! So here, we are speaking about the language and speaking it constructionally and structurally correctly! However, I thank you for your comment and taking the time ti reply to me question.

Comment: But @A-friend it is a matter of logic. Women like that do not exist, whatever culture you're in. If you're looking for a word, check out *sycophant*.

Comment: Well @FeliniusRex I know many words like sycophant, toady, flatterer, bootlicker etc. Here, I brought up another topic about the proper way of using the word "game" as it can informally refer to a willing person (say a girl in my case,) which is rather than be a naysayer or a wet blanket tries to be game and takes part in various occasions which her boyfriend suggests and in return expect her boyfriend to treat in the same way! I've encountered many of these girls in many countries. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a specific/sexual application of "a game girl" but I would not use it as it just doesn't sound right – if I saw/heard it I wouldn't really know how to parse it. I can't justify it in terms of grammatical rules, as it should be possible to have an adjective before a noun(!), but I can't find any examples of this usage in the various dictionaries I have or online and I have never read/heard it.

I would always use "a girl who is game for anything" rather than "a game girl".

Comment: I would advise extreme caution when using the expression 'a game girl' in the UK or any British English speaking country. Certainly among unthinking, sexist/misogynist males from about age 12 onward, (maybe even most) a 'game girl' or a 'girl who is game for anything' is one who, they hope, is game for exactly one thing.

Comment: I agree that using 'game' to mean 'willing' sounds both sexual and derogatory, in the UK. You definitely shouldn't use 'game' to describe another person. The only exception is if it's clear from the context that you mean something else, eg: "Are you game to go to the concert later?"

Comment: I would not use 'game' (in a non-sexual-derogatory way) to simply mean 'willing'. If a person is 'game' they are 'willing to do things that are new, difficult, or that involve risks' [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/game)

Comment: Never, ever, say that a female person in Britain is 'on the game'.

Comment: Very true, and I should have considered the nuances in my answer rather than just the linguistics. I’ve certainly used “game” when referring to myself, but only in situations that are qualified such as “Do you fancy trying the new pub that’s opened?” “Yes, I’m game.” and I agree that the unqualified “game for anything” could be open to misinterpretation.

Comment: Around 1968, the family was watching a BBC TV play (possibly by Frank Norman) in which   one Cockney character said "My wife's mother was on the stage". His pal said "On the game, more like". Both characters (and my parents) laughed. I was 16. I asked my mother what the phrase meant. She said "Ask your father", but he wouldn't tell me.